# Stream does not support reading when placing a HTTP Post request

Tags: c#, http-post, filestream

I am facing an error that is "Stream does not support reading". I am placing a Http post request to the url. Below is my code that what i am using

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://test.com/Hotel Hospitality Source?method=fetchInfo");

var postData = "&username=testing";
postData += "&password=Testing";
postData += "&hotelId=h075-103";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
request.GetRequestStream().CopyTo(ms);

var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Firstly I have used below code.

```
 using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
 {
     stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
 }

 var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

 var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

[image]

I am getting error when I am using CopyTo method for stream. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: That's not a error at all. That's the debugger being unable to show the `Length` property because the request stream does not support it. Just don't look at this line, the program should work fine regardless. If you have another issue, please specify exactly what it is, that is what error you are getting.

Answer (score 6):

What is `using (var ms=new MemoryStream()) request.GetRequestStream().CopyTo(ms);` supposed to do? You're trying to copy the request stream (which is write-only) into a new memorystream that you then dispose.

You need to write into the request stream:

```
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: I Have used this but when  I am using this a error is occurring that is "This stream does not support seek operations"

Comment: using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

Comment: That code does not throw that exception. Show all relevant code and all relevant errors for that code.

Comment: That error is thrown by the `request.GetRequestStream().Length`, because **that is a write-only stream**. Simply don't do anything with the request stream but writing to it.